# Staggered photo frame of selected images

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-custom-view, staggered-gridview

I'm bit curious to know that how [EyeEm App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baseapp.eyeem&hl=en) achieve the *selected photos staggered frame* without loosing image aspect ratio which looks pretty, I googled but didn't found similar and same I want to achieve I came across [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) but it doesn't work as *EyeEm app*, AsymmetricGridView loose image aspect ratio/stretch images etc.

**For reference#** Attached EyeEm app staggered image (Same I want to do).
[image]
[image]

Can someone shade the light?

**Edited**

May be it suggestion based question but really I want to know as I want to achieve something similar and as I said I tried one of custom staggered but that doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Comment: I think though they maintain the image aspect ratio, they should crop the images. Otherwise it will be impossible.

Comment: no, they are cropping image, they display same uploaded image.

Comment: @jaibatrik why would they do that? while they can write something that do scale the images to their needs.

Comment: @RobinHood hi.. have you achieve this view?

Answer (score 3):

you could use this library [Github](https://github.com/500px/greedo-layout-for-android)
it does exactly what you asked for by using their LayoutManager instead of the normal LayoutManager provided by the SupportLibrary, it also let you specify the maximum height that your image can't exceed while maintaining its aspect ratio.